# Can I somehow toggle off or at least turn down my GeForce RTX 2080 Ti graphics card when not needing it?

Tags: graphics-card

I own a `GeForce RTX 2080 Ti` which was very expensive and therefore I only would like to use it when playing games like BF5 or Star Citizen. The thing is I more often play World of Warcraft Classic and therefore do not need it's performance.

Is there a way to toggle the card at runtime to save it's power while not needing it?

Greetings!

**EDIT**: Since people are downvoting my question I think it's because they assume it is the wrong topic

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about...computer hardware, etc.

It seems it in fact is the right place.

Comment: You will be unable to dynamicly disable your GPU from within Windows.

Comment: So can I turn it off in BIOS then?

Comment: You might be able to disable the PCIe slot but if that’s possible it would be an option in the firmware.  Are you trying to make your system consume less power.  Disabling the PCIe slot won’t  decrease the amount of power your system uses just will make the card inaccessible to the OS

Comment: I just kinda wanna switch to onboard graphics for the poor graphic games to give the RTX more rest ( wanna have it life as long as possible )

Comment: People downvote you because they think this question is a joke. The lifespan expectancy of a GPU is longer than most people have before the card is very slow compared its competition so it is far liker that you will not town down your card and buy a new one eventually because you just want an upgrade, rather than it dying. If you were GPU mining, it would be a different case, but you are not listing that. The most logical answer therefor is going to be: follow your current path without alterations and you will be fine.

Comment: @xetra11 - What you describe will not impact the lifespan of the card.

Comment: Don't all BIOS/UEFI firmware settings allow one to toggle between binary _(CPU integrated)_ and discrete _(GPU card)_ graphics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those classical X/Y problems. You think you have a problem, came up with a solution and are stuck with it and requesting help for that particular solution.

The problem here is that your problem definition is not correct. I have to assume here that you want to spare your GPU because you are afraid it will break and you have to buy a new one, because it was very expensive.

This is a wrong assumption. Your GPU was manufactured in such high degree that it can take a really lot of punishment before it dying. If you use it like a normal gamer does, you will still have a working GPU by the time you decide to upgrade to a newer GPU. GPU's tend to last for more than 8 years, but by this time, newer games and stuff won't run on it anymore and you will have to upgrade anyway. Getting any mechanic in it to use it less is basically throwing away money because you paid to get performance you are denying yourself. The card will hold, so don't look for ways to tone it down, unless you want to mine cryptocurrencies with it, but even then, you will need to push the cards to its max for a considerably long time before you get any value of your cryptomining that you basically buy the cards for that purpose only, and not to game with it.

Comment: Perfectly said, the gamers reading this would be obliged.